# How to pass captured URL to Email Body in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am stuck at one place, i want to capture the url and print into the email body through HTML but not able to do the same. Request you to help on this. code is below.... this code is auto generated by a device i am just modifying to my need.

```
<html>
This site has been blocked. If you believe this is an error,<br>
kindly contact to Mr. ABC - +9112345678
<br>Or you may <a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com?cc=xyz@gmail.com&subject=Google Website $$Category$$&body=<script>document.write(document.URL);</script>">Send Email</a>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of document.url try, window.location.href

Comment: Kindly forgive me as i am newbie for this, actually what is the problem whatever i used to pass in the body it takes it as text.  I have tried so many things but didn't work. hence request you to kindly elaborate how to use this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about passing the href value with JS?

```
<a id="Mail" href="#">Send Email</a>

<script>
    (function() {
        var mail = document.getElementById("Mail");
        var url = window.location.href;
        var href = "mailto:abc@gmail.com?cc=xyz@gmail.com&subject=Google Website $$Category$$&body=" + url;
        mail.href = href;
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you can try this code to pass url to E-Mail body.

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.test?body=Link goes here http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ffoo.php%3Fthis%3Da%26join%3Dabc%26user454
">Link text goes here</a>
```

Comment: This is fixed link, i need to capture the URL for current IE Tab.